# Using ifelse and as.yearmon together

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, zoo

I have some issues using an 'ifelse' statement together with 'as.yearmon' from the zoo package.

My initial dataset is similar to 'df'. From it, I'd like to calculate the duration of each row. So first, I created a column with the start date ('initdate') and then another column with the end date ('enddate'), which must correspond to the suspension date if there is any, or to the current date if there is none.

Here is my code:

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)

df <- data.table(id=c(1:3), month1=c(3,2,5), year1=c(2011,2012,2014), monthsusp=c(2,NA,NA), yearsusp=c(2012,NA,NA), weight=c(1,1,1))

#Add column with concatenated 'month year'
df$initdate <- as.yearmon(paste(df$month1,df$year1, sep = "-"),"%m-%Y")

#Create 'current date’
date <- Sys.Date()  #to get current system's date
x <- format(date,"%m")
y <- format(date,"%Y")
df$curmonth <- x
df$curyear <- y

#Add column with current date OR suspension date if any
df <- transform(df, enddate = ifelse(yearsusp > 1, monthsusp, as.yearmon(paste(df$curmonth,df$curyear, sep = "-"),"%m-%Y")))
```

I only get NAs when there is no suspension date... I don't understand why. Can you help, pretty please?
Note that I'm very new to R, which is why my coding might be a little awkward (especially the 'create current date' section) :)

Cheers,

Fred

Comment: I don't really understand what resulting data you expect/want to see for this example..?

Comment: It's just a preliminary step. Your comment below (almost) answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want the end result to look like the `initdate` column...

```
# wrap the conversion in a function
myym <- function(m,y){
    if (is.numeric(m)) m <- sprintf("%02d",m)
    as.yearmon( paste(m,y,sep="-"), "%m-%Y")
}

# initialize to the current yearmon
df[, enddate := myym(curmonth,curyear) ]

# overwrite with the yearmon from the data if available
df[ !is.na(monthsusp) , enddate := myym(monthsusp,yearsusp) ]
```

This gives

```
   id month1 year1 monthsusp yearsusp weight initdate curmonth curyear  enddate
1:  1      3  2011         2     2012      1 Mar 2011       08    2015 Feb 2012
2:  2      2  2012        NA       NA      1 Feb 2012       08    2015 Aug 2015
3:  3      5  2014        NA       NA      1 May 2014       08    2015 Aug 2015
```

A couple things to note:

- Mind the classes of your inputs and outputs. `enddate` cannot sometimes be a number and sometimes be a string.
- If you're using data.table, you can and should refer to columns without the `$`; and should create columns using `:=` instead of `df$newcol <-` or `transform`. Check out [the excellent tutorials](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) to get started.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I still have an issue with my actual dataset, as I get the following error message when initializing to the current yearmon:
"Error in `:=`(enddate, myym(curmonth, curyear)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")."

I haven't figured it out yet, but will look into it. I have a few other columns in the 'real' dataset, so that might be why...

Comment: @Fred-LM It looks like `df` is not yet a data.table. You could follow the guidance in that message to check, typing `is.data.table(df)`. If it's not a data.table, use `setDT(df)` to convert it into one ("in place," so there's no need to assign the result like `df2 <- setDT(df)`)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)